# Drawing image by using Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a question regarding to Canvas, here is my code of drawing something:

```
   .....
   <script>

  function drawImage(imageObj) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

    var imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
    var data = imageData.data;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
      var brightness = 0.34 * data[i] + 0.5 * data[i + 1] + 0.16 * data[i + 2] + 0.18 * data[i + 3];

      data[i] = brightness;

      data[i + 1] = brightness;

      data[i + 2] = brightness;

      data[i + 3] = brightness;
    }


    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  }

  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    drawImage(this);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'lena.jpg';
  </script>
.....
```

This is one part of my code which is Canvas in JavaScript, it instructs the image to be grayscale, it works fine to display the image in the browser, please note the last command is load the image from its source (imageObj.src = 'lena.jpg';), however, when I put this command to the first line in the script, the browser does not show anything, I do not know why it must be in the end of the script, please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    drawImage(this);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'lena.jpg';
```

where would the the first line be?

The Script basically the script has 5 lines and starts here like this.

```
1. var imageObj = new Image();
2. imageObj.onload = function() {
3.   drawImage(this);
4. };
5. imageObj.src = 'lena.jpg';
```

Puting on the first line would look like this:

```
imageObj.src = 'lena.jpg';
var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    drawImage(this);
  };
```

But the image was not created at that point.

This should work also:

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = 'lena.jpg';
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    drawImage(this);
  };
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, what I mean is when I put imageObj.src = 'lena.jpg'; above  function drawImage(imageObj) {.... , then it will not display the image in browser, but if I put in the end like the code in my question, it displays properly, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

The onload function has to be defined before the source. Otherwise it can happen, that the image will be loaded and the onload function is not even defined. Therefore the `imageObj.src = 'lena.jpg';` has to be at least after the `imageObj.onload`.

But you could move that whole block before the `drawimage` function. that should work fine

Comment: Hi. thank you for your comments, so what make the onload function has to be defined before the image loaded then?

Comment: Sorry i dont understand the question... Can you rephrase that?